# Can Blogger disable URL redirection automatically after a third-party domain expires?

Tags: blogger, domain

I have a blog at Blogger.com and I have purchased a custom domain from a third-party provider. On Blogger, I have set the original address *ihatemeteorites.blogspot.com* to be redirected to *ihatemeteorites.cz*.
Now, let's say I die tomorrow (after a meteorite falls on my house). After a year or so, the third-party domain expires and no longer exists or worse, someone else buys it. The question is: Will *ihatemeteorites.blogspot.com* be redirected to *ihatemeteorites.cz* even after the domain is expired and will my blog therefore become inaccessible and lost forever? Or can Blogger tell somehow that the domain has expired and will disable the redirection automatically so that my blog becomes accessible at *ihatemeteorites.blogspot.com* again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly Blogger **could** choose to observe that the domain has expired and disable the redirection automatically so that your blog becomes accessible at ihatemeteorites.blogspot.com again.

But for now, they **don't** do this.   Visitors to your blog will continue to be redirected to  ihatemeteorites.cz  even once someone else has loaded entirely new content to that domain.

(Your best bet is to keep away from meteorites!)